# `column` colors broken with linux-utils 2.30

Tags: linux, terminal, colors, unix-utils

I am using the `column` command to parse the output of a `git for-each-ref`.

With linux-utils 2.29 everything works, but with 2.30 colors are not rendered in my terminal:

```
git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate \
    --format='%(color:yellow)|%(committerdate:relative)|%(HEAD)%(color:bold green)%(refname:short)%(color:reset)|%(contents:lines=1)' \
    --count=8 \
    refs/heads | column -ts'|'
```

Before:

[image: with colors]

After:

[image]

This seems to be related with this entry in the release notes:

> The command "column -t|--table" has been modified to use libsmartcols.

I would submit a bug report at [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/category/contact-us.html), but that page just redirects me here.